# Fortran program stuck on deallocation

Tags: fortran, allocation

This is a snippet of my fortran code where it gets stuck:

```
   if(allocated(this%basis)) then
      print  *, "basis is allocated "
      deallocate(this%basis)   
      print  *, "destroyed basis "
   end if
```

The "basis is allocated" is printed to the terminal, but the "destroyed basis" is not printed. The program appears to be stuck on the deallocate() command. Has anyone had experience with what could be causing this?

Edit - I don't know if this is related, but I also noticed that I cannot quit the program using "Ctrl+c." I have to do a "Ctrl+z" to quit the program.

Comment: How very peculiar.  I think a [mcve] might be necessary.

Comment: I tried to duplicate this problem with a simple code, but I cannot. I also cannot paste the entire program because it is too large. I'm really not sure how else to go about providing more details, but yes, this is very strange that it is getting stuck on the deallocate() line. My understanding is if something's allocated, then it should easily be able to be deallocated. I cannot think of anything that could prevent this.

Comment: I did try a deallocate(this%basis, stat=dest) and I tried to output 'dest' but I can't output it because the program is still stuck in the deallocate command.

Comment: I saw something similar from https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/269360 . I don't really understand his solution to the problem nor the problem that he described in the last post.

Comment: I will check on that. I just ran my program with Valgrind, and it worked just fine. It didn't get stuck on the deallocation. I wonder if it's a memory leak problem.

Comment: A final subroutine could cause such symptoms.  Although, it's very unlikely this is the case for you.

Comment: I don't know what is going on. I changed nothing, and ran the code again and now the 2nd print statement prints. But the code gets stuck on a subsequent deallocation. I will look into this more later.

Comment: Usually, a DEALLOCATE gets stuck when a memory error has occurred  somewhere BEFORE the deallocate statement (setting an array out of bounds for instance). Use valgrind to try and detect such error.

Comment: *"I tried to duplicate this problem with a simple code, but I cannot. "* This is exactly why a *real* [mcve] is needed! You do not start from scratch when making one, you delete unnecessary stuff piece after piece and you check that the error is still there. Sooner or later you have a small enough piece of code. Often you find the error yourself.

Comment: You can try adding some compilation flags and see if that helps you find the error: `-check pointers` and `-check uninit` or just `-check all`.  This assumes you are using the Intel compiler, since you referenced the Intel website in a comment.  I'm not sure of the GNU equivalents.

Comment: In addition to what has already been said, you could trying moving the `deallocate(this%basis)` statement upwards in the code. For example, you could put it immediately after the allocate statement and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: I used valgrind and found out that I incorrectly allocated one of my arrays. This array that I incorrectly allocated was used to compute this%basis. Fixing this appeared to have fixed my error. S